# What I am doing wrong in this binary tree program

Tags: c++, binary-tree

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

struct node{
    int data;
    node *left;
    node *right;
};

node *root ;
node *newnode;

void insert( node **root , int value){
    newnode = *root;

    if ( newnode == NULL ){
        newnode = new node;
        newnode->left = NULL;
        newnode->right = NULL;
        newnode->data  = value;
    }
    else if ( value < newnode->data ){
        insert( &newnode->left , value );
    }
    else if ( value > newnode->data  ){
        insert ( &newnode->right , value );
    }
}

int main(){

    node *p = root;
    insert ( &root , 4);
    insert ( &root , 5);
    insert ( &root , 2 );

    cout << root->data << endl;
    //inorder( root );
}
```

It is giving this error

```
    [main] C:\Users\abc\Documents\QueueUsingLinkedList.exe 1336 (0)      handle_exceptions: Exception: STATUS_ACCESS_VIOLATION
    [main] QueueUsingLinkedList 1336 (0) handle_exceptions: Dumping stack trace to QueueUsingLinkedList.exe.core
    [Finished in 0.7s]
```

I am making this binary tree from past hour... I have seen programs on internet but I don't know what is wrong with this program.

Comment: Start with using your debugger to find where it happens

Comment: Please consider removing consecutive blank lines from your code when posting. Extra blank lines makes even small amounts of code require needless scrolling to see everything.

Comment: As @deviantfan it's better to learn to use a debugger - there are [youtube tutorials](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eEJ5xKO7c3o)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
node *root = NULL;
```

and

```
*rootnode = newnode;
```

EDIT:

Try this:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

struct node{
    int data;
    node *left;
    node *right;
};


void insert( node **rootnode , int value) {

    node* newnode = *rootnode;

    if ( newnode == NULL ) {
        newnode = new node;
        newnode->left = NULL;
        newnode->right = NULL;
        newnode->data  = value;
        *rootnode = newnode; // this was missing!
    }
    else if ( value < newnode->data ){
        insert( &newnode->left , value );
    }
    else if ( value > newnode->data  ){
        insert ( &newnode->right , value );
    }


}




int main(){

    node* root = NULL;

    insert ( &root , 4);
    insert ( &root , 5);
    insert ( &root , 2 );

    cout << root->data << endl;
}
```

Comment: I simplified the code. perhaps it will be better now ;-)

Comment: insert method doesn't have any effect.

Comment: OK, I've compiled it and it works now. I should have done this in the first place to avoid downvoting.

Comment: @eespdg , yes it did worked but why do i need " *rootnode = newnode; "  .. because i have assined "  node* newnode = *rootnnode " , How will it make any difference

Comment: If you accept my answer, I will tell you why ;-) This is because rootnode is pointer to pointer. After you allocate new node, you need to put the allocated node pointer to caller's leftnode or right node.

Comment: The caller gives the argument &newnode->left and this is the address of the pointer to left node. Function needs to set the address of new node to this pointer. That is what *rootnode=newnode does.

Comment: Thank you for accepting my answer! Happy programming!

Answer (score 1):

You never change the value of `root` in `insert()`:

```
if ( newnode == NULL ){
    newnode = new node;
    newnode->left = NULL;
    newnode->right = NULL;
    newnode->data  = value;
    *root = newnode; // the root is the newly create node...
}
```

Also initialize `root` to `NULL`.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few things that would be clearer if you structured your program a little more:

> 1 - You should use constructors!

`struct`s and `class`es can both have constructors defined, so you should use them: they'll save you a lot of code in the long run.

```
struct Node {
  int data;
  Node *left;
  Node *right;
  Node(int data) {
    this->data = data;
    left = NULL;
    right = NULL;
  }
  ~Node() {
    delete left;
    delete right;
  }
};
```

> 2 - You should have a Tree class of some sort!

If you have a tree class, you don't need to worry about passing a root around - the class will take care of it for you assuming you define the correct behavior. ;)

```
class BinaryTree {
  public:
    BinaryTree() { root = NULL; }
    ~BinaryTree() { delete root; }
    bool insert(int inserted);
    Node* get_root() const { return root; }
  private:
    Node* root;
};
```

> 3 - Your insert should return a `bool`

It's typical for operations like `insert`, `search`, and `remove` to return a `bool` - this lets the caller know if it was successful. I'll define success in this case as `insert`ing a node with a unique value.

```
bool BinaryTree::insert(int inserted) {

    if(!root) {
        root = new Node(inserted);
        return true; // This is a unique value
    }
    else {
        Node *temp = root;

        while(temp) {
            if(inserted > temp->data) {
                if(temp->right)
                    temp = temp->right;
                else {
                    temp->right = new Node(inserted); // This is a unique value
                    return true;
                }
            } else if(inserted < temp->data) {
                if(temp->left) 
                    temp = temp->left;
                else {
                    temp->left = new Node(inserted); // This is a unique value
                    return true;
                }
            } else
                return false; // Not unique
        }
    }
    return false; // Just in case
}
```

> 4 - A few minor things

I'd recommend capital names for `struct`s and `class`es. In fact, it's traditional to name them using `UpperCamelCase`. Variables should either be `lowercase` or `snake_case` - I've made some changes in the code. For more style recommendations, you should check out [the Google Style Guide for C++](https://google.github.io/styleguide/cppguide.html). It's really nice.

[Here's the ideone.](https://ideone.com/SBy9jq) Good luck with the rest of the implementation. :)